# Is here a place for report - without a question?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I noted a problem. I made a heavy testing and I discovered a fundamental discrepancy between theory and practical realization. I spent an extra time to write a short report, and I tried to posted it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625307/). But I got a comment saying it is an off-topic. Well, if you agree, do I have to delete that post. (?)

Comment: Your post is fine even though they don't think so. So I upvoted your post and voted to reopen it. They also downvoted my post into invisible https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/lets-return-to-the-full-meaning-of-unix-linux.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the title of your question: no, SE's format does not support Questions in the form of "reports". Each Question should have a problem that has a solution (Answer). Self-answers are completely acceptable, too, if you've found an interesting problem *and* have found a solution to it.

As I said on your question, if you're trying to understand the discrepancy you've found, ask that. You've done a great job describing the results (along with excellent ASCII diagrams!), but when you say:

> I do not expect any solving of this problem, but your experience and opinions are welcome.

... that leads your question directly off-topic.

As to your existing Meta Answer here: while you've done great research, SE is also not a bug report forum, nor a way to alert project or kernel developers.

Sharing knowledge is a big part of SE; the format simply demands a Question with a question in it, followed by one or more Answers.

You've had a U&L account for a couple years now, and have provided other valuable Questions and Answers. It does take some time to get used to the way things work around here, so I'd encourage you to take a moment to reflect on your RAID question and see whether there's **a** problem that someone in this community can answer. If, instead, it's ongoing research or part of a bug report, consider tracking down the developers who are responsible for that code and approach them with your results.

Answer (score -2):

Let me say my opinion, based on the offer to: *Answer your own question – share your knowledge*. What I did: I posted me a question, I did a testing, and even I did not solved the problem, I have identified deeper system issues that only project and kernel developers can solve. Hence I vote to accept my post, because I share my knowledge throu it.

Answer (score -3):

I appreciate your attempt to defend your position, Jeff and the others, but let me explain my point of view: Have a look at [allowed type of question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and carefuly read the final paragraph. I also edited and expanded my post with new measurement and knowledge.
I respect your fear of endless discussions and even flames, but I did not start any.

Thanks for your careful judgement.